# Sorting class fileds while conversion it to json using Gson

Tags: java, json, gson

I create class for json representation:

```
class MyClass {
    public long a;
    public String c;
    public String b;

    @Override
    public toString(){
        return new GsonBuilder().create().toJson(this)
    }
}
```

I use it:

```
MyClass c = new MyClass();
c.a = 10;
c.b = "b";
c.c = "c";
String json = c.toString();
```

I have json like next:

```
{"c":"c","b":"b", "a":10}
```

But I want to have:

```
{"a":10, "b":"b", "c":"c"}
```

How can I sort field in json? (Using Gson or other methods)

In real project i have more complex structure with inheritance and lists of other objects.

Comment: Note that there is no ordering in a JSON object's name value pairs. What you want is unneccesary.

Comment: Do you want them orderered alphabetically?

Comment: Yes, I do. And now I have wrote own code with sort result json with out using gson.

Comment: any work around/fix for this issue @HotIceCream ?